# Access to Rapla through Glype

Tags: php, curl

There is a [Rapla](https://code.google.com/p/rapla/) event planner running at my work. It is set to be accessible only from computers in our office, though (IP check?). I needed to have an access also from my home, but the administrator won't reconfigure Rapla. However, I have an sftp account at the server (which is the same as the one where Rapla is running - same IP addressess; this server is accessible from Internet at browser's port 80, since we have our homepage running there).

I figured out, that I can upload [Glype](https://www.glype.com/) proxy script to my acoount and run it like this from any IP address: www.mycompany-domain.com/myfolder/glype/index.php. It really works and redirects me to a lot of websites, while showing my company server's IP. However, when I try to connect to a 8051 port (Rapla's port) through Glype, I get the cURL error:

> The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the
>   error: Failed to connect to /here goes the IP/: Permission denied

Later on, I found a script called Glypeahead, which, according to the author, should fix this issue. I wasn't able to find any info how to use it and being myself just an amateur programmer, I am stuck at this moment.

So, my question is the following: how can I connect, using Glype, to Rapla's port 8051? I am open to any non-Glype solution too :-).